# PostGIS: ST_Equals false when ST_Intersection=100% of geometry?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-statistics

I have 2 datasets consisting of cadastral parcel data - roughly 125,000 rows each. The geometry column is WKB polygons representing parcel boundaries; all data are geometrically valid (the polygons are closed etc).

Some recent data arrived in a different projection to the base data being used for a comparison job - so I reprojected the newer one (base was 4326; the other was WGA94 that got brought into PostGIS as 900914... I reprojected it to 4326).

The first stage of the analysis was to find and store non-matching parcels; part of that is to identify and store parcels with identical geometry.

So I ran a very standard query (the code block below abstracts away schema details etc):

```
create table matchdata as
  select  a.*
  from gg2014 a, gg2013 b
  where ST_Equals(a.g1,b.g1)
```

ZERO results.

"Odd..." I thought. "Perhaps there have been tiny vertex shifts caused by the reprojection: that would be annoying, and really shouldn't happen."

Fortunately there is abundant aspatial data (5 identifier columns) that enable me to establish parcels that should be spatially identical: those with the same identifier, whose change-date in the 2014 table was before the max change-date in the 2013 data. That amounted to 120,086 distinct rows.

I stored the identifiers and geometries in a separate table (`match_id`), and ran the following query:

```
select apid, 
       bpid, 
       ST_Area(ag::geometry) as aa, 
       ST_Area(bg::geometry) as ab,
       ST_Area(ST_Intersection(ag,bg)::geometry)/ST_Area(ag::geometry) as inta,
       ST_Area(ST_Intersection(ag,bg)::geometry)/ST_Area(ag::geometry) as intb
from match_id
order by inta
```

The first 16 values for `inta` and `intb` were identically zero, the next 456 were 0.99999999-ish (min 0.99999999999994, max 0.999999999999999), and rows 473 onwards were 1 - until row 120050, when the area of the intersection was *greater than* either geometry (the greatest value for `inta` and `intb` was 1.00000000000029, but still).

So here's my conundrum: if two geometries intersect spatially by between 99.999999999994% and 100.000000000029% of their respective areas, I would like "ST_Equals" to say "Yep.... I'll give you that one. Close enough".

After all, it's equivalent to being out by about 1 part in 16 trillion... i.e., as if the US national debt was off by less than 93 cents.

In the context of the circumference of the Earth (at ~40,000km), it's like being off by 0.0000000025km, tops (since to result in an area difference that small, any vertex shift must be even smaller).

According to TFD (which I have R'd) the tolerance for `ST_Intersects()` is notionally 0.00001m (1mm), so the implied changes in the vertices (which I confess I have not checked: I will `ST_Dump()` them and do so) would seem to be smaller than the tolerance. (I realise that `ST_Intersects !== ST_Intersection()`, but it's the only tolerance mentioned).

I have not been able to find out the corresponding tolerance for the vertex comparison undertaken by `ST_Equals()`... but it seems really odd that at least 120,000 of my rows ought to pass any sensible assessment of spatial identity, but don't.

(Note: I also did the same exercise using `::geography` - with results that had more variability, but still more than 110,000 entries with a nice clean '1').

Is there a way to loosen the tolerance of ST_Equals, that doesn't require digging into the interstices of the code? I am not keen on doing that.

If not, is there a kludge that anyone is aware of?

Note: it would be good if the 'kludge' wasn't doing a bilateral comparison like

```
where ST_within(g1, ST_Buffer(g2, 0.0000001))
  and ST_within(g2, ST_Buffer(g1, 0.0000001))


   - I've done that: sure, it works... but it's a gigantic documentation PITA).
```

I can work around this, but writing the 20 pages to document the workaround - which will only ever come up again if we get dodgy data - is a PITA that I would rather not have to do given that it's likely to be a one-off.

(Versions: Postgresql 9.3.5; PostGIS 2.1.3)

Comment: Just a thought here, but have you tried to canonicalize the new parcels to a grid which is conformable with the excisting data using st_snaptogrid ?

Comment: I can understand not wanting to look at the source code, but your question induced me to do so (even though my C++ sucks), so I thank you for that. If you are interested I can post the relevant sections, which are all in https://github.com/libgeos.

Comment: `ST_Equals` only returns `true` when geometries are *equal* -- geometry type, number of vertices, SRID, and vertex values (in all dimensions, in the same order). If there is any variance, comparison stops, and `false` is returned.

Comment: @Vince: as I understand it (from the docs), `ST_Equals()` ignores directionality. I took that to mean that for a closed 2-D polygon, it makes no difference if the points are enumerated clockwise vs anti-clockwise. `ST_OrderingEquals()` is the tighter test. That said, having inspected the vertices (using `ST_Dump()` and calculating deltas for every vertex) it's clear that @John Barça's awesome answer is on the money. `ST_equals()` is contraindicated, even for *ex-ante* known-identical data, if one geometry is reprojected - unless the comparison is made with ST_SnapToGrid().

Comment: Late back to this: nice quick way to get an acceptable test for spatial [near-]equality is to check what proportion of each geometry is part of the intersection. It's a bit computationally burdensome; calculate `(100*(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.g1, b.g1))/ST_Area(a.g1)))::int as int_pca` and `(100*(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.g1, b.g1))/ST_Area(b.g1)))::int as int_pcb` ( make sure your `JOIN` includes `ST_Intersects(a.g1,b.g1)`). Test if `(int_pca, int_pcb)=(100,100)` (or some other set of cutoffs). Kludgy, but it'll do 2.6 million parcels in ~30min (so long as g1 is GIST indexed).

Comment: Also give ST_HausdorffDistance a try. You might find it useful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My guess is that you coordinate transformations have introduced tiny rounding errors (see an example below). As there is no way to set the tolerance in ST_Equals, this is causing ST_Equals to return false for some geometries that only differ in the nth decimal place, as the geometries have to be identical in every respect -- see the [intersection matrix definition in libgeos](https://github.com/libgeos/libgeos/blob/svn-trunk/include/geos/geom/IntersectionMatrix.h#L297). You can check this with a really extreme example,

```
SELECT ST_Equals(
      ST_MakePoint(0,0),
      ST_MakePoint(0,0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001));
```

which returns **false**.

If you use [ST_SnapToGrid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) you can impose a given precision, for example, to ten decimal places,

```
SELECT ST_Equals(
      ST_MakePoint(0,0),
      ST_SnapToGrid(
             ST_MakePoint(0,0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001),
      10));
```

now returns **true**.

If you were to run,

```
CREATE table matchdata AS
SELECT  a.*
FROM gg2014 a, gg2013 b
WHERE ST_Equals(ST_SnapToGrid(a.g1, 5), ST_SnapToGrid(b.g1, 5));
```

setting an appropriate tolerance, I suspect your problems would disappear.

Here is a link to a [Postgis developer discussion about tolerance](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/ToleranceDiscussion) which suggests it is less than trivial to implement.

I did a couple of conversions between British National Grid (EPSG:27700) and lat/lon to illustrate the point about rounding precision, taking a point somewhere in London,

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(525000, 190000),27700),4326));
```

returns `POINT(-0.19680497282746 51.5949871603888)`

and reversing this,

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(-0.19680497282746, 51.5949871603888),4326),27700));
```

returns `POINT(525000.000880007 189999.999516211)`

which is off by less than a millimeter, but more than enough to make ST_Equals return false.

Comment: John Barca's answer is correct - that tiny rounding errors can throw ST_Equals off. My (unpleasantant) experience was when working with two data sets - both projected from EPSG 4326 to EPSG 3857 - one via ArcCatalog *(ArcToolbox -> Data Management Tools -> Projections and Transformations)*, while the other one via GDAL ogr2ogr.

Comment: This answer has helped me a lot. But I noticed that geographic indexes were no longer used and queries took way too long. My workaround was to create temporary tables with the snapped geometries and add indexes to them before running the query. Is there a better way to speed things up?

Comment: @hfs. I believe you can make a functional index using ST_SnapToGrid.  You are correct that using a function call inside an equals/intersects/contains etc spatial operation will cause the index not to be used and making a functional index would solve this. Or you could permanently update your data if you think the precision is spurious and then not to have to use ST_SnapToGrid in the query. It depends on your data and use case, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Did you run ST_IsValid check on your geometries?  If they are invalid, all bets are off.  ST_Intersects and the other family of GEOS spatial relationship functions will often just return false because the area is not well-defined from an intersection matrix point of view.  The reason doing ST_Buffer probably works is because it's converting your invalid geometries to valid ones.  ST_Buffer(...,tinybit) is what is known as a "poor man's try to make my geometry valid" tool.

Comment: The very first step with any new dataset is selecting only valid geometries using `ST_isValid(g1)` -  that was mentioned (obliquely) "[t]he geometry column is WKB polygons representing parcel boundaries; *all data are geometrically valid (the polygons are closed etc)*."

Answer (score 1):

My answer comes a bit late, but maybe it will help someone that has the same problem. From my experience, when two geometries that are indeed equal but ST_Equals returns False two things may help:

1. make sure that comparing geometries are single geometries (No MultiLinesting, MultiPoin etc.)
2. try `ST_Equals(st_astext(a.geom), st_astext(b.geom))`  instead of `ST_Equals(a.geom , b.geom)`

The first one is already mentioned in the [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Equals.html).
The second one seems irrational but works. I don't know, but guess it has to do with the binary format of default postGIS geometry.