# ST_Equals not matching with exact geometry

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-database

I followed many question posted on the same subject but unable to solve my problem.

I have same kind of tables in 2 different database (tables with linestring geometry), I need to update id from one table to another when it finds equal geometry in another table.

table1 from DB1 looks like bellow.

```
     Column      |           Type           |
-----------------+--------------------------+
 old_id          | bigint                   | 
 road_id         | bigint                   | 
 road_name       | character varying(255)   | 
 geo             | geometry(Geometry,4326)  |
Indexes:
    "roads_final_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("old_id")
    "roads_final_wkb_geometry_geom_idx" gist (geo)
```

and table2 of DB2 is as bellow.

```
   Column    |          Type           |
-------------+-------------------------+
 id          | bigint                  |
 object_id   | bigint                  |
 geoproperty | geometry(Geometry,4326) |
Indexes:
    "geofeature_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "geoproperty_idx" gist (geoproperty)
    "object_id_idx" btree (object_id)
```

Before updating I just checked how many of them are matching, like bellow.

```
select count(*) from (select * from dblink('port=5432 dbname=db2 user=usr password=pass','SELECT geoproperty from table2' as t(geoproperty Geometry)) r,table1 t1 where st_equals(t1.geo,r.geoproperty);
```

But it is returning only 10-15% of matches where I was expecting more than 90% match because they are same geometry copied to DB2 and updated `object_id`.

I also tried with `st_snaptogrid`,`st_buffer` and `st_astext` with geo columns, But they are taking huge amount of time compared to regular st_equals method.

But when I cross checked with non matched id's geometry from table1 with geometry in table2 with normal

```
select * from st_equals(st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(.line from table1.)'),st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(.line from table2.)'))
```

It is returning `true` but not matching with first (count/select) query.

Is there anything I am missing ?

Comment: Is there a significant difference in postgis versions between both databases?

Comment: No. I am using postgis 2.1 in both databases. Does change in postgis makes any changes to st_eqaul operation?

Comment: Change in st_equal wouldn't matter, but there could be a tiny chance on small differences in the way Geometry is being described. Also I am not sure what happens when sending data in a DBLink, did you try copying the whole (or part of) the table into the other database first?

Comment: I created a view from foreign database table using dblink and tried the same. But not usefull.

Comment: Comparing geometries as text is not reliable. Slightly different binary geometries may convert into same WKT because of the floating point inaccuracy.

Comment: @user30184 what can be done?

Comment: Use [ST_SnapToGrid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) possibly? I wrote this [answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141790/postgis-st-equals-false-when-st-intersection-100-of-geometry/141822#141822) some time ago which may be of some help.

Comment: Use pgAdmin and select a.geom, b.geom where you believe that they should be identical.  Look closely if they really are.

Comment: Attempting join on a double is risky.  Atttempting join on lines is twice the number of vertices riskier (and ***very*** inefficient).  Instead, use an integer primary key.